# Using sensitive data from other apps

Tags: android

I have 3 apps say A1,A2,A3. A1 and A2 are existing well established businesses example, amazon and uber. Is it possible in a way to display say the cumulative amounts spent in A1 and A2 til date securely in A3 for the logged in user? If yes how would I be able to?

Comment: You can't just mine data like that from other apps. Those companies would have to explicitly provide you access through an API or some other method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really get those specific analytics using the sdk methods. You can have the information about the apps currently running, on the basis of currently running apps, you can get some information you're looking for. There might be some undocumented methods available. But with the newer security system, it would be difficult so sniff the data/information of the other apps.